# ¿Cómo poner las etiquetas en la parte inferior del gráfico?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buen día con todos, estoy desarrollando un gráfico logarítmico como se muestra a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las etiquetas de cada punto se sitúan justo a lado del punto, y esto es lo que no quiero, porque lo que busco es que las etiquetas se sitúen en la parte inferior del gráfico, justo en la dirección en el eje x que le corresponda.

Su codificación con código duro es la siguiente:

```
Series series = Chart1.Series["Series1"];
Series seriesPuntos = new Series();
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(76.20, 100.0);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(63.50, 100.0);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(50.80, 100.0);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(38.10, 100.0);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(25.40, 98.6);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(19.05, 90.0);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(12.70, 83.0);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(9.53, 75.9);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(4.75, 59.8);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(2.36, 46.8);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(1.18, 39.3);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(0.85, 36.8);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(0.60, 30.7);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(0.42, 27.1);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(0.30, 25.7);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(0.25, 24.0);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(0.18, 21.9);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(0.15, 20.6);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(0.10, 19.7);
seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(0.074, 18.3);
Chart1.Series.Add(seriesPuntos);

Chart1.Series[1].XValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
Chart1.Series[1].YValueType = ChartValueType.Double;

Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
Chart1.Series[1].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;

Chart1.Series[0].Color = Color.DarkRed;
Chart1.Series[0].BorderWidth = 1;
Chart1.Series[0].BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;

Chart1.Series[1].Color = Color.DarkRed;
Chart1.Series[1].BorderWidth = 15;

Chart1.ChartAreas[0].BorderWidth = 1;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 2;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 100;

Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 90;

series.Points.AddXY(76.20, 100.0);
series.Points.AddXY(63.50, 100.0);
series.Points.AddXY(50.80, 100.0);
series.Points.AddXY(38.10, 100.0);
series.Points.AddXY(25.40, 98.6);
series.Points.AddXY(19.05, 90.0);
series.Points.AddXY(12.70, 83.0);
series.Points.AddXY(9.53, 75.9);
series.Points.AddXY(4.75, 59.8);
series.Points.AddXY(2.36, 46.8);
series.Points.AddXY(1.18, 39.3);
series.Points.AddXY(0.85, 36.8);
series.Points.AddXY(0.60, 30.7);
series.Points.AddXY(0.42, 27.1);
series.Points.AddXY(0.30, 25.7);
series.Points.AddXY(0.25, 24.0);
series.Points.AddXY(0.18, 21.9);
series.Points.AddXY(0.15, 20.6);
series.Points.AddXY(0.10, 19.7);
series.Points.AddXY(0.074, 18.3);

Chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
Chart1.Series[0].YValueType = ChartValueType.Double;

Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 90;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelAutoFitStyle = LabelAutoFitStyles.LabelsAngleStep90;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLogarithmic = true;

Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "% QUE PASA EN PESO";
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.TitleFont = new Font("Roboto", 11, FontStyle.Bold);

Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "ABERTURA (mm)";
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.TitleFont = new Font("Roboto", 11, FontStyle.Bold);


Chart1.Series[0].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
Chart1.Series[0].LabelBackColor = Color.White;
Chart1.Series[0].LabelAngle = 90;

Chart1.Series[0].IsXValueIndexed = true;
Chart1.Series[1].IsXValueIndexed = true;
```

Vista:

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" BorderlineWidth="14" Width="990px" Height="450" class="card-img-top" Style="width: auto; !important">
            <Series>
                <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Line"></asp:Series>
            </Series>
            <ChartAreas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
            </ChartAreas>
            <Titles>
                <asp:Title Font="Roboto, 12pt, style=Bold" Name="Title1" Text="CURVA GRANULOMÉTRICA">
                    <Position Height="3.862135" Width="92" X="8" Y="1" />
                </asp:Title>
            </Titles>
        </asp:Chart>
```

Lo que busco es que las etiquetas de cada punto se sitúen en la parte inferior del gráfico como se muestra a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución a este problema fue proporcionada gracias a [Bruno Canettieri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5170189/bruno-canettieri)

La pregunta en inglés es la siguiente: [Enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64971517/how-to-put-labels-at-the-bottom-of-the-chart/65012920#65012920)

Consiste en agregar una segunda matriz con el eje Y en cero, de esta forma poner las etiquetas deshabilitadas para la primera matriz con eje XY, para sólo habilitar las etiquetas del segundo matriz con un ángulo de 90 grados.

```
var seriesPuntos = new Series();
foreach (var point in series.Points)
{
    seriesPuntos.Points.AddXY(point.XValue, 0);
}

seriesPuntos.XValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
seriesPuntos.YValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
seriesPuntos.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
seriesPuntos.BorderWidth = 0;

seriesPuntos.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
seriesPuntos.Label = "#VALX";
seriesPuntos.SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = false;
seriesPuntos["LabelStyle"] = "Bottom";
seriesPuntos.LabelAngle = -90;

Chart1.Series.Add(seriesPuntos);
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
```